# Property 'TestingButton' does not exist on type 'ProductContexts | null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm currently learning TSX and ReactJS using context in my shopping carts lesson
here is the code in my context file

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

type cartsProps = {
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  name: string;
  img: string;
  price: number;
  saleprice: number;
}[];

type ProductContexts = {
  carts: cartsProps;
  TestingButton: () => unknown;
};

export const ProductContext = createContext<ProductContexts | null>(null);

type MyContextProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
export function TestingButton() {
    console.log("pressed")
}

const handleTestingButtonClick = () => {
  TestingButton();
};

export default function MyContextProvider({ children }: MyContextProps) {
  const [carts, setCarts] = useState<cartsProps>([]); // Updated here to match the type

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ carts,TestingButton: handleTestingButtonClick }}>
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
  }
```

and here is my the line i used in Product.tsx to use the context

```
import { ProductContext } from "./ProductContext";
type ProductContexts = {
  TestingButton: () => void;
};
const {TestingButton} = useContext(ProductContext)
```

I am not experienced so I tried using AI model to solve it and using documents but i dont know how to fix it and i am honestly stucked right now, thank you everyone and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. First check if context is not null and then it should be OK:

   ```
   import { ProductContext } from "./ProductContext";

   const someComponent = ()=> {
   const context = useContext(ProductContext)
   if(context === null) return null;
   const {TestingButton} = context
   ....
   ```

   *Notice that hooks such as `useContext` are called inside of component.*
2. better solution for me, don't allow it to be null and just set default values:

   ```
   export const ProductContext = createContext<ProductContexts>({
   carts: undefined,
   TestingButton: ()=> throw Error("Not in provider")
   });
   ```

   or something similar to this.

Comment: Thanks, i followed through and managed to use my context now, cheers!